# Convert image to webp after adding watermark on image

Tags: laravel, image, watermark, webp, intervention

I am currently working on a project on which I have to add watermark to image and then convert the image into webp format.I come up with two libraries to do so but they both require uploaded image as parameters, but after adding watermark the input for the webp library becomes object of Image Intervention.

**This is my Laravel Controller Code**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use File;
use Webp;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

public function store(Request $request)
{
 foreach ($request->image as $img) {

            $destinationPath = 'uploads/auction';
            $watermark = 'uploads/auction/logo.png';
            $originalFile = $img->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename=  uniqid().'-'.time().'-image.jpg';
            $name = $destinationPath.'/'.$filename;
            $img = Image::make($img);
            $img = $img->insert($watermark, 'bottom-right', 1, 1);
            $img->save($name);
            WebP::make($img)->save($name);
        }
}
```

Can anyone provide me a solution to achieve this??